# Select the id of a specific row in a table

Tags: php, database

I have a list of data:

```
id  |  username  |  name  | product  | date
```

Now, I have a varying amount of rows.

Eg:

```
1  |  bob123  |  John Doe  |  1/1/2000


3  |  steven30  |  John Bradley Doe  |  3/5/1998
```

etc....

Now, I have a button attached to each row.
When the button is clicked, I want to be able to detect the `id` of that row. For example, I press the button on `bob123`'s row. I want the PHP to echo the id of that row, which is one. Is there any way to do this?

```
$idSelect = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM data WHERE id='<detect id here>'");
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: yes it is possible, but, what have you tried? can we see your html?, and how you want it?.. via $_POST(), or via $_GET();?... AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML file

```
<a href="file.php?id=1" role="button" rel="nofollow">BOOB1234</a>
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && (INT)$_GET['id']) {
 echo 'ID is: ' . $_GET['id'];
exit;
}
```

Of curse you might need to do more stuff in the php... I have no idea how you want it, but you can try that...